# Why I am getting this error "The SDK location is inside studio install location." in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, sdk

As I am a beginner in app development, It was the first time I am installing the android studio. But i stuck with this error **An error occur while trying to compute the require package**. I have 32 bit operating system I have to download zip file
I have stored my android studio file in desktop as`C:\Users\good pc\Desktop\android-studio` so i thought that i have to change the sdk location path in Studio as well. i have given the sdk path as`C:\Users\good pc\Desktop\android-studio\jre`but now it is giving error as **The SDK location is in studio install location**. I couldn't understand how to resolve this issue so I am posting it. this question is not asked frequent so i couldn't get it on stackoverflow.
Edit :- if I give it the default SDK path it throw a error like SDK is missing

Comment: You need to set Android SDK location to SDK

Comment: Youre giving android SDK path to android JRE. Change it to the location of SDK

Comment: I have not got any file of android SDK and the jre is the only thing which has possible my studio to go further otherwise it has giving error that SDK is missing or corrupted